# Выполняет команды но не у всех группах

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Проблема такая... в одной групе работают эти команды в другой нет. И там и там бот админ и емеет доступ к сообщениям. В чем прикол?

```
   async def set_default_commands(dp):
        await dp.bot.set_my_commands(
            [
                types.BotCommand("weather", " Погода"),
            ]
        )
    
   @dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.TEXT)
   async def commands_messages(message: types.Message):
       if message.text == " Погода":
           await command_weather(message)
       elif message.text == "Привет":
           message.reply('и тебе привет!')
   
   @dp.message_handler(commands='start')
   async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
       await message.answer("Хотите узнать прогноз погоды?", reply_markup=config.MAIN_MENU)
```

Comment: Что значит «нет», что происходит вместо работы? И почему функция `commands_messages` находится внутри функции `set_default_commands`?

Comment: Это я тут в редакторе немного не правильно вставил. commands_messages  стоит отдельно от set_default_commands